# Олимпиадная задача. Кирпичи

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ограничение времени 1 секунда
Ограничение памяти  64Mb

**Условие**

Вася решил выложить бордюр из кипричей для дорожки на своем участке. Расположенный по соседству кирпичный завод выпускает кирпичи длиной A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, …, A<sub>m</sub>. Промоутеры завода раздают потенциальным клиентам по 2 кирпича бесплатно. Вася взял по 2 кирпича каждого типа и теперь хочет узнать, может ли он выложить из них бордюр длиной N и толщиной в один кирпич.

**Формат ввода**

Сначала вводится число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 109), затем — число M (1 ≤ M ≤ 15) и далее M попарно различных чисел A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, …, A<sub>m</sub> (1 ≤ Ai ≤ 109).

**Формат вывода**

Выведите сначала K — количество кипричей, которое нужно использовать для выкладывания бордюра, если можно выложить бордюр длиной ровно N. Далее выведите K чисел, задающих длины использованных кирпичей. Если решений несколько, выведите вариант, в котором Вася использует наименьшее количество кирпичей. Если таких вариантов несколько, выведите любой из них.

Если для выкладывания бордюра придется обязательно разломить какой-то кирпич, то выведите одно число 0. Если же у Васи не хватит кипричей, чтобы выложить бордюр, выведите одно число –1 (минус один).

**Пример 1**

*Ввод*

```
5 2

1 2
```

*Вывод*

```
3

2 2 1
```

**Пример 2**

*Ввод*

```
7 2

1 2
```

*Вывод*

```
-1
```

**Пример 3**

*Ввод*

```
5 2

3 4
```

*Вывод*

```
0
```

Kод:

```
def can_get(a, m):
    s = {0}
    for n in a:
        if n <= m:
            b = [x + n for x in s if x + n <= m]
            s.update(b)
    return m in s

n, m = map(int, input().split())
a = [int(_) for _ in input().split()]
a = sorted(a * 2)[::-1]

answer = []

if min(a) > n:
    print(0)
elif n < sum(a):
    if can_get(a, n):
        while n != 0:
            if (n - max(a) >= 0) and (can_get(a[1:], n - max(a))):
                n -= max(a); answer.append(max(a))
            a = a[1:]

        print(len(answer)); print(*sorted(answer))
    else:
        print(0)
elif n == sum(a):
    print(len(a)); print(*a)
else:
    print(-1)
```

Но она неверна, на 17 тесте выдает неправильный ответ (данные теста мне неизвестны).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Нашёл, почему наши решения не проходили 17 тест - оба выдавали неправильный ответ при следующих вводных данных:

   ```
   20 5
   8 7 6 2 1
   ```

   Ответ:

   ```
   4
   2 2 8 8
   ```

   Хотя возможен вариант:

   ```
   3
   7 7 6
   ```
2. После исправления этой ошибки, моё решение с использованием динамического программирования стало доходить до **23** теста, где получало **RE**. На своём компьютере я не смог воспроизвести ошибку, подсовывая программе разнообразные тесты, однако понял, что такой алгоритм здесь не годится, так как по условию `N <= 10^9`. Это означает, что для нахождения ответа требуется построить таблицу размером `10^9 * M`. Длина кирпича также может достигать `10^9`.
3. Сдал задачу используя алгоритм из этого видео (на английском): [Sum Of Subsets Problem - Backtracking](https://youtu.be/kyLxTdsT8ws).

#### Решение №1

Объяснение на примере

```
20 5
8 7 6 2 1
```

**1)**
Находим все возможные суммы, которые можно получить из последовательности `8 7 6 2 1`. Если какую-либо сумму можно получить разными вариантами, выбираем тот, в котором используется меньше чисел/кирпичей. Складываем всё в словарь вида `сумма` : `самая короткая последовательность`. Получаем следующий словарь:

```
{0: [], 
 1: [1],
 2: [2],
 3: [2, 1], 
 6: [6],
 7: [7],
 8: [8],
 9: [8, 1], 
 10: [8, 2], 
 11: [8, 2, 1], 
 13: [7, 6], 
 14: [8, 6], 
 15: [8, 7], 
 16: [8, 7, 1], 
 17: [8, 7, 2], 
 18: [8, 7, 2, 1], 
 21: [8, 7, 6], 
 22: [8, 7, 6, 1], 
 23: [8, 7, 6, 2], 
 24: [8, 7, 6, 2, 1]}
```

**2)**
Перебираем элементы этого словаря, проверяя можно ли получить требуемую длину (`20`). Например, берём элемент `13: [7, 6]`, до `20` не хватает `20 - 13 = 7`. Проверяем есть ли такой ключ/сумма в словаре. Есть -  `7: [7]`. Значит, можно получить `20`, соединив две последовательности кирпичей: `[7, 6]` и `[7]`. Пишем в ответ. Если в процессе будет найдена более коротая последовательность, заменяем ответ на неё и т.д.

Этот метод работает, так как по условию у нас два одинаковых набора кирпичей. Можно сказать, что первую последовательность мы берём из одного набора, вторую из другого набора.

```
def solve():
    length, brick_type_num = map(int, input().split())
    bricks = list(map(int, input().split()))

    bricks_sum = sum(bricks)
    if bricks_sum * 2 < length:
        return -1

    min_len_sums_dict = {}
    # Функция для наполнения словаря "min_len_sums_dict" всеми
    # возможными суммами.
    # Ключ = сумма; значение = последовательность кирпичей, образующая эту сумму.
    # Значение заменяется при нахождении более короткой последовательности кирпичей,
    # для данной суммы.
    def min_len_sums(cur_sum, residue, pos, accum):
        if cur_sum not in min_len_sums_dict:
            min_len_sums_dict[cur_sum] = accum
        else:
            min_len_sums_dict[cur_sum] = min(min_len_sums_dict[cur_sum], accum, key=len)

        if pos >= len(bricks):
            return
        # Включаем текущий кирпич в сумму
        min_len_sums(cur_sum + bricks[pos], residue - bricks[pos], pos + 1, accum + [bricks[pos]])
        # Не включаем текущий кирпич в сумму
        min_len_sums(cur_sum, residue - bricks[pos], pos + 1, accum)

    min_len_sums(0, bricks_sum, 0, [])

    min_len = float('inf')
    min_len_subseq = None
    # Ищем в словаре с суммами два элемента, ключи которых образуют требуемую длину
    # бордюра и имеют самую короткую последовательность кирпичей при этом.
    for a_sum, a_bricks in min_len_sums_dict.items():
        b_sum = length - a_sum
        if b_sum in min_len_sums_dict:
            b_bricks = min_len_sums_dict[b_sum]
            overall_len = len(b_bricks) + len(a_bricks)

            if overall_len < min_len:
                min_len_subseq = b_bricks + a_bricks
                min_len = overall_len 

    if not min_len_subseq:
        return 0

    result = ' '.join(map(str, min_len_subseq))
    return f"{min_len}\n{result}"

print(solve())
```

**Тестирование** (в `bash`)

```
# Команда показывает содержимое 8-ми файлов:
$ tail -n +1 input_*    

==> input_1.txt <==
5 2
1 2

==> input_2.txt <==
7 2
1 2

==> input_3.txt <==
5 2
3 4

==> input_4.txt <==
20 5
3 4 6 7 8

==> input_5.txt <==
29 4
15 14 7 7

==> input_6.txt <==
12 5
1 3 4 5 11

==> input_7.txt <==
15 15
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

==> input_8.txt <==
20 5
8 7 6 2 1


# Запускаем скрипт для каждого файла
$ for f in input*; do echo "${f}"; ./solution.py < "${f}"; echo; done
```

**Output**

```
input_1.txt
3
2 1 2

input_2.txt
-1

input_3.txt
0

input_4.txt
3
6 7 7

input_5.txt
2
15 14

input_6.txt
2
1 11

input_7.txt
15
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

input_8.txt
3
6 8 6
```

---

#### Решение №2

Работает намного быстрее первого. Сочетает в себе метод поиска с использованием половины кирпичей из **решения №1** и динамическое программирование. В отличие от **решения №3** не строит таблицу `N * M`, а хранит значения всех возможных сумм в `set`. Одновременно с поиском всех возможных сумм, обновляет словарь минимальных последовательностей, которыми эти суммы можно получить.

```
def min_len_sums_calc(bricks):
    dp_calc_set = {0}
    min_len_sums_dict = {0 :[]}

    for a_brick in bricks:
        new_sums_set = dp_calc_set.copy()   

        for b_brick in sorted(dp_calc_set, reverse=True):
            new_sum = a_brick + b_brick
            new_sums_set.add(new_sum)
            new_subset = [a_brick] + min_len_sums_dict[b_brick]

            if new_sum not in min_len_sums_dict:
                min_len_sums_dict[new_sum] = new_subset 
            else:
                min_len_sums_dict[new_sum] = min(min_len_sums_dict[new_sum], new_subset, key=len)

        dp_calc_set = new_sums_set

    return min_len_sums_dict    

def find_min_len_subseq(length, min_len_sums_dict):
    min_len = float('inf')
    min_len_subseq = None
    for a_sum, a_bricks in min_len_sums_dict.items():
        b_sum = length - a_sum
        if b_sum in min_len_sums_dict:
            b_bricks = min_len_sums_dict[b_sum]
            overall_len = len(b_bricks) + len(a_bricks)

            if overall_len < min_len:
                min_len_subseq = b_bricks + a_bricks
                min_len = overall_len 

    return min_len_subseq

def solve():
    length, brick_type_num = map(int, input().split())
    bricks = list(map(int, input().split()))

    if sum(bricks) * 2 < length:
        return -1

    min_len_sums_dict = min_len_sums_calc(bricks)
    min_len_subseq = find_min_len_subseq(length, min_len_sums_dict)

    if not min_len_subseq:
        return 0

    result = ' '.join(map(str, min_len_subseq))
    return f"{len(min_len_subseq)}\n{result}"

print(solve())
```

**Input**

```
2500 100 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

**Output**

```
27
100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 81 100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93

real    0m0,155s
user    0m0,150s
sys 0m0,004s
```

---

#### Решение №3

Рабочее, но не прошедшее тесты.

Попытка решить задачу методом динамического программирования, используя алгоритм из этого видео (на английском): [Subset Sum Problem Dynamic Programming](https://youtu.be/s6FhG--P7z0). Метод рабочий, на всё мои тесты даёт правильный ответ, но не подходит для больших чисел. Для полноты картины прилагаю.

```
def fill_col_to_end(table, from_row, col, value):
    for row in table[from_row:]:
        row[col] = value

def find_bricks_subset(table, bricks):
    row = len(table) - 1
    col = len(table[0]) - 1
    result = []
    rotated_table = list(zip(*table))

    while col > 0 and row > 0:
        row = get_min_value_row(rotated_table[col][:row + 1])
        brick = bricks[row - 1]
        result.append(brick)
        col -= brick 

    return result

def print_table(table):
    for row in table:
        for col in row:
            col = 0 if col == float('inf') else col
            print(col, end=' ')
        print()

def get_min_value_row(values):
    return min(range(len(values)), key=values.__getitem__)

def build_lengths_table(bricks, length):
    width = length + 1
    height = len(bricks) + 1
    table = [[float('inf')] * width for _ in range(height)]
    value = 0
    fill_col_to_end(table, 0, 0, value)
    for row in range(1, height):
        brick = bricks[row - 1]
        for col in range(brick, width): 
            value = table[row - 1][col - brick] + 1
            if value < table[row][col]:
                fill_col_to_end(table, row, col, value)

    return table

def solve():
    length, brick_type_num = map(int, input().split())
    brick_type_lst = list(map(int, input().split()))

    if sum(brick_type_lst) * 2 < length:
        return -1

    brick_type_lst.sort()
    bricks = [brick for brick in brick_type_lst for _ in range(2)]

    table = build_lengths_table(bricks, length)


    if table[-1][-1] == float('inf'):
        return 0

    bricks_subset = find_bricks_subset(table, sorted(bricks))

    result = ' '.join(map(str, bricks_subset))
    return f"{len(bricks_subset)}\n{result}"

print(solve())
```

Comment: Выдает неправильный ответ на 12 тесте

Comment: @asdfjsldfksjdsdjklas Можете дать ссылку на тестирование? Или там только для своих?

Comment: Зайти туда может каждый, но это будет показано в положении участников. Ссылка - https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/18132/problems/F/

Comment: @asdfjsldfksjdsdjklas Поправил своё решение, теперь тоже доходит до 17 теста. 17-ый тест "Wrong answer". На моих тестах работает как задумано. Пробовал делать проверку входных данных, чтобы `input().split()` возвращал ровно столько чисел, сколько указано и проверку на уникальность (неповторяемость) типов кирпича - не помогло.

Comment: @asdfjsldfksjdsdjklas Смотрите обновление ответа.

Comment: "Рабочее решение" хорошее для данных условий (мало предметов). Решение ДП вообще требует одномерной таблицы длиной N, двумерная зря используется. Но в любом случае 10^9 ячеек памяти использовать расточительно - просто bottom-up DP  здесь не к месту, а memoization подошло бы. Однако умное использование парности кирпичей в рабочем решении позволяет обработать меньший набор, вроде meet-in-middle метода. +